# Enable touchpad acceleration (21.04, Wayland)

Tags: touchpad, 21.04, synaptics, wayland

Moving my finger 3 cm over the touchpad moves the cursor across approximately half the screen, regardless how quickly/slowly I do it.

That means I either can't easily hit a click target (current settings) or can't quickly move across the screen. Normally, I'm used to touchpads moving "faster" on fast movements (i.e. moving your finger quickly by 3 cm moves the cursor across the entire screen, moving the finger slowly for 3 cm only moves the cursor a little bit).

Is there some way to enable/adjust this?

```
$ sudo libinput list-devices
Device:           SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
Kernel:           /dev/input/event6
Group:            8
Seat:             seat0, default
Size:             70x50mm
Capabilities:     pointer gesture
Tap-to-click:     disabled
Tap-and-drag:     enabled
Tap drag lock:    disabled
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: disabled
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   *two-finger edge 
Click methods:    *button-areas clickfinger 
Disable-w-typing: enabled
Accel profiles:   flat *adaptive
Rotation:         n/a
```